# How can I do client validation to form with ASP.NET MVC 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, mvvm, asp.net-mvc-5

I am new to ASP.NET MVC 5. I like to learn the correct way to build a two way binding between the view and the view model. And take advantage of the client side validation script.

Here is what I have done.

1. I loading jQuery Library v 1.10.1
2. I loading [Jquery-Validation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/)
3. I loaded [jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation/3.2.3)

I created a ViewModel like so

```
public class RequestFormViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Day Of")]
    public DateTime LocalFrom { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Does not matter since this will be hidden and I use javascript to populate the value here when before the for is submitted")]
    public DateTime From { get; set; }

    public RequestFormViewModel()
    {
    }

    public RequestFormViewModel(DateTime localFrom, DateTime from)
    {
        this.LocalFrom = localFrom;

        this.From = from;
    }
}
```

And this is how I created my view. Note that I pass a presenter or a business layer (i.e. `DefaultViewPresenter`) to my view and not the ViewModel. The class `DefaultViewPresenter` has a property nammed `Request`. (Below I will show how my presenter looks like)

```
@model Proj.Presenters.DefaultViewPresenter

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Track", FormMethod.Post, new { @class="form-inline", Id = "TrackActionForm" }))
{ 
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Request.LocalFrom, new { Id = "TrackFrom", Name = "From" })                   

    <div class="input-group">

        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Request.LocalFrom, new { Value = Model.Request.LocalFrom.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"), @class = "form-control small", Id = "TrackLocalFrom", Name = "LocalFrom" })
        @Html.ValidationMessage("LocalFrom")

        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-info" type="button" id="TrackSubmit">View</button>
        </span>

    </div>

}
```

Here is how my presenter looks like

```
public class DefaultViewPresenter
{
    public RequestFormViewModel Request { get; set; }
    .... // some other propertied that I need for the view that are not related to my form
    ....
    ....
}
```

**Problem**

When I submit the form, the form does not get submitted! I don't I get any errors. Its like the submit button has `return;` function on the click event.

How can I get the script to validate correctly and when the form is valid processed the post request?

What am I missing here? How can I correct this problem?

After running my app this is the HTML markup that is razor is generating

```
<form novalidate="novalidate" id="TrackActionForm" action="/Track" class="form-inline" method="post">
    <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" value="thmJX-Mlj5WjM3e7WMbgtb8KiEf4vuUKGzon4zO18fHDDY3cWpm2M1Lks8HbZDxX2qz7UxpRsoYvz2njNwYS_D8zclTvu9pdsJlSO0ckNLQ1" type="hidden">
    <input id="TrackFrom" name="From" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field Day Of must be a date." data-val-required="The Day Of field is required." value="9/14/2016 12:00:00 AM" type="hidden">                    
    <div class="input-group">

        <input id="TrackLocalFrom" name="LocalFrom" value="09/14/2016" class="form-control small" type="text">
        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="LocalFrom" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>

        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-info" type="button" id="TrackSubmit">View</button>
        </span>

    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few issues with your implementation.

All the `HtmlHelper` methods that generate form controls generate the correct `name` and `value` attributes necessary for 2 way model binding. You are overriding those values so that the controls now have no relationship to your model.

You also have a hidden input for the `Request.LocalFrom` property before the textbox, so that when you submit, only the value of the hidden input (the original value of the property) will be bound and the edited value in the textbox will be ignored. In addition, because of that hidden input, the `data-val-*` attributes generated for client side validation have been applied to the hidden input, not the textbox.

Its not clear why you need 2 view models, and ideally your `DefaultViewPresenter` view model should contain properties for `LocalFrom` and `From`, however with your current models, your view needs to be

```
@model Proj.Presenters.DefaultViewPresenter

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Track", FormMethod.Post, new { @class="form-inline", Id = "TrackActionForm" }))
{ 
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken() 
    <div class="input-group">          
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Request.LocalFrom, "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", new { @class = "form-control small" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Request.LocalFrom)

        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-info" type="submit" id="TrackSubmit">View</button> // change to a submit button
        </span>
    </div>
}
```

Note the 2nd parameter in `TextBoxFor()` is the format string, but that can be omitted if you use the `[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]` applies to the property. Note also the `HtmlHelper` methods generate an `id` attribute based on the property name and there should generally be no reason to overwrite it.

As a side note, it is recommended that in your view models, you make value type properties `nullable` with the `[Required]` attribute to protect against under-posting attacks (where a malicious user posts backs and omits a name/value pair for the property, in which case it will be initialized to its default value (`DateTime.MinValue`).

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter ...")]
[Display(Name = "Day Of")]
public DateTime? LocalFrom { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help here. The validation is still not working for me. When I click the `View` button nothing happens. I expected the form to get submitted. Additionally, now the value in the `LocalFrom` shows date and time. I only want to show the date without the time. I added `[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]` to my ViewModel and removed the second parameter in the `@Html.TextBoxFor` what could be causing the form not to submit?

Comment: Ahh. Your 'VIew' button is just that - its a button. Change it to `type="submit"` or use `<input class="btn btn-info" type="submit" value="View" />`. Then if you clear the text from the textbox and click 'View', you will get an error message displayed.

Comment: Also if you use the `DisplayFormatAttribute`, then you also need `ApplyInEditMode = true` and use `EditorFor()` For the moment, stick with using the 2nd parameter in `TextBoxFor()` to format the value

Comment: Errr silly mistake. thank you. Now the form submits but if I don't put a value in the field it also submits. There is no validation that is taking place. also I am still seeing date and time even after adding `ApplyInEditMode`   here is what I have `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Request.LocalFrom, new { @class = "form-control small", ApplyInEditMode = true })`

Comment: Did you remove the hidden input? Check the html your generating - you should now see `<input name="Request.LocalFrom" id="Request_LocalFrom" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field Day Of must be a date." data-val-required="The Day Of field is required." value="9/14/2016" type="text" />`

Comment: no the hidden field is needed. Why would I need to remove it? I need to pass two values

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123394/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-jaylen).

Answer (score 0):

By default JQuery Validation ignores hidden fields for client side validation. Try the following in a script block in your view or _layout.cshtml:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
 $.validator.setDefaults({ ignore: [] });
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: it is also ignoring the text input just just the hidden

Comment: Are you saying other fields are being ignored rather than just the hidden ones?

Comment: that is correct. the `text` fields are being ignored. According to jQuery Validation, the property should have `required` attribute. I was thinking that Razor will automaticly add that for you since I have the property marked as Required in the ViewModel

Comment: Is that before or after adding this script? When you add a required attribute to a property in the model used by the razor view, the framework does render the necessary html for the field to be validated properly on the client side. Are you confident `$.validator.setDefaults({ ignore: [] });` is being executed?

Comment: I updated my question to make it more clear and after fixing couple problems with the HTML code

Comment: Your HTML shows you have a value in the hidden field. Are you hoping for `MM/DD/YYYY` validation? If you are then this field is valid. Likewise for  `TrackLocalFrom`